# Redirection 301 htaccess file uppercase and spaces

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a problem with 301 redirect from old to new page. The problem is that the old directory has spaces and capital letters and Google gives me an error. I put one of the examples:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 https://carretonselevadors.com/Carretons%20Elevadors%20Castellano/index.php https://carretonselevadors.com/quienes-somos.php
```

Comment: Is `https://carretonselevadors.com/Carretons Elevadors Castellano/index.php` your source URL?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. you need to use `NE` flag for your rules to consider characters as their actual meaning. Also please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Now You can Fix Redirect issue by C Panel.
First of All you have to go C Panel login,
Second step click redirection
choose 301 for Permanent redirection
301: Old Ulr to New Url